Can a telegram bot access the user's camera directly or using Web Apps?
Can a telegram bot directly or using Web Apps access the user's camera in real time if the user has given the appropriate permission? For example, to create an online broadcast?
As far as I know, it is not possible to do this directly through a telegram bot, but using a browser it is possible. And as I understand Telegram uses its built-in browser, the question remains whether it is possible by means of Web Apps to interact with the built-in telegram browser to gain access to the smartphone/PC camera, to implement online broadcasting.
If possible, tell me how to implement it, please, or in which direction to at least move.

As a yes/no question, this is kind of off-topic: even if you get an answer, that answer won't really help future visitors: what (re)searching did you already do? Because Stackoverflow is basically a last resort, not the first.

The fact that it is possible to implement this through a browser, and Telegram uses its built-in browser to implement Web Apps, as I understand it.

Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow, but your question is off-topic. Although your question is about programming, as it's currently written, you're asking for a full implementation of a project. However, SO is intended for question asking for "how to solve a problem", usually with error messages, or "how to write this code", which yours is similar but usually these types of questions ask for very short and simple code. Please first consult [Tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], and [help/dont-ask] before posting a question.
